# What type of visa is required to be allowed to earn a PPL in the US?

Tags: flight-training, ppl, tsa

What are the visa types (H1b, L1b, H4, L2, J1, etc) accepted by TSA to learn flying for recreational purposes?

### UPDATE 1

I found some further information from [National association of flight instructors](http://www.nafinet.org/news.aspx?id=370), According to them; Person on work visa can follow Part 61 course and get the PPL.

### UPDATE 2

I have received the permission from the TSA to flow the Category 3 flight training. It took around 1 & 1/2 weeks to process and it will cost around 130 for the application and 99 for fingerprint process.

Based on this process, I understood that L1 Or L2 Or H1 Or H4 holders are eligible with the right set of document and no criminal record.

Comment: I got there on a F1 vor my PPL and Instrument rating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a foreigner to come to USA to learn to fly, one would need an [F-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_visa) or [M-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-1_visa) visa.

[This article in Flying magazine](http://www.flyingmag.com/training/flight-school-getting-student-foreign-visa) provides some information. You can get more information on [from this school](https://www.afa.edu/pilot-programs/international-pilot-training/)<sup>1</sup>. Also, you can look at this meta question: [Can I ask about details of coming to the US to get a PPL?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1506/65)

**Update:**

It appears that you are already in the US on [H-1b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa) visa (it wasn't mentioned in the question), you need to go through the security clearances mentioned in [Alien Flight Student Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Flight_Student_Program) (official version on [TSA website](https://www.tsa.gov/stakeholders/training-and-exercises-0)).

AOPA has put together the related information ([website](http://www.aopa.org/Pilot-Resources/Flight-Instructor-Resources/AOPAs-Guide-to-TSAs-Alien-Flight-Training-Citizenship-Validation-Rule/Aliens-and-Non-U-S-Citizens-Seeking-Flight-Training)). I also found about [this flight school](http://www.theflightschool.com/afsp.htm)<sup>1</sup> which has outlined the process.

If you search on Google about *Alien Flight Student Program*, you will find a ton of information.

---

<sup>1</sup>: **Disclaimer** I am not advertising any flight school.

Comment: Those visas are the primary student visa types, and would allow a foreigner to come to the U.S. *specifically* to attend a flight school (flight school is a "vocational training program" and so people coming specifically to get a pilot's license would probably get an M-1). Another possibility is an H-3, if you live in a country that has no aviation education facilities locally and you're not trying to become a commercial pilot. Immigrant visas leading to permanent residency would also qualify. You might also be able to train on your own time while in the U.S. on other business, such as an H1B.

Comment: KeithS, Do you have any reference for the statement of H1B holders can learn for the recreational purpose>?

Comment: @Vanji I've updated my answer as it appears you are already in the country.

Comment: @Vanji - http://www.askacfi.com/9242/are-non-us-citizens-eligible-for-private-license.htm. In short an H1B visa holder, like any, is subject to a TSA review process, but with their approval, any valid visa holder can receive flight instruction in the U.S. and obtain various levels of FAA pilot's license. It's a little unfeasible for vacation visa holders because the review process can take the entire time they're legal to be here, but just because you're in the U.S. for one reason doesn't mean that's the only thing you can legally do while you're here.

Comment: Great, thanks lot for informative answer.

Comment: @Farhan, Do you know which course that is accepted by TSA? Is it Part 61 and 141 ?

Comment: @Vanji I'm not sure, probably both as the end goal is the same, that you'll be a pilot. I couldn't find any information on TSA's website. Maybe you can get it during or after the registration process.

Comment: Any information for while you're already in US with F-1 for different program and you're working on STEM OPT? AOPA mentions what if you're in US on F-1 visa and still enrolled for course you can but nothing mentioned for specific scenario that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably need [an M-1 visa](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/study-exchange/student.html) for flight training, though you may also be permitted to do flight training on an F series visa (e.g. if it's in conjunction with a college aviation degree program).

This is not really a TSA matter (aside from the parts relevant to [the Alien Flight Student Program](https://www.flightschoolcandidates.gov/afsp2/?acct_type=c&section=WN)), but rather a [State Department matter](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english.html). To confirm the specifics and determine which visa type is most appropriate for your planned course of study you should contact the state department (or [the US embassy/consulate in your home country](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/find-a-u-s--embassy-or-consulate.html)).