# Does flight training have any impact on my H1B visa?

Tags: flight-training, usa, tsa

I'm on an H1B visa, working in the IT industry and I need to know if I take flight training after getting an AFSP clearance from the TSA, does that affect my current visa or IT job?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having flight training has no effect at all on your visa status. It's actually the other way around: your visa status can determine [whether or not you can have flight training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16888/62). But you can definitely get flight training with an H1B.

And flying has no special impact on your job: how you choose to spend your free time is none of your employer's business. There could be some very specific scenarios where flight training and work intersect, e.g. if your company is in the aviation sector you might be able to get them to pay for training. Or if you're a very senior executive at a very large company then the Board of Directors might have concerns about you spending your time on 'risky' activities. But otherwise, flying has nothing at all to do with your work.

Comment: `flying has no special impact on your job: how you choose to spend your free time is none of your employer's business` In most cases, and for most people, yes. I have talked to people, particularly in the financial sector who are specifically barred by employment agreement from participating in many outside-work activities. Honestly, I don't think pilot training would be one of the barred activities, but the statement is a little bit _too_ blanket. i.e. Don't let random strangers on the internet get you fired & risk deportation. Be sure it's OK with _your_ employer.

Comment: Freeman is correct. Some employers set restrictions on "high risk activities" for (usually some of) their employees to mitigate corporate risk in case they die or become long term disabled. Flight training may or may not fall under such depending on the whiles of some HR flunky (more often it's meant to stop people from bungee jumping, parachute jumps, and rock climbing).

Comment: I talked to one of the flight school and they said I can start ground school with part 141, and when I checked the link provided by pondlife in the above message, it is indicated that h1b visa holders are eligible for part 61, does that part 61 or part 141 really matter? or can I take part 141? please advise, Thanks in advance!