# Flight Training in US as an Alien

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, flight-school, tsa

I am currently living in the UK, engaged to a US citizen and we are looking to marry and move to the US. The plan is to travel to US with a K1 Visa as fiancé, get married there and apply for adjustment of status. This would give me the right to live there, not work until work permit is issued.

1. Will I be able to start flight training with a flight school without work permit? Would I be able to apply for AFSP or would I need to wait for Adjustment of Status? Most flight schools seem to offer US Citizen or International Students option and I'm not sure which category I would fit in my situation.
2. Would I be able to obtain a FAA Medical with K1 Visa? Are these unrelated?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16888/62)